# why is will_paginate throwing an expected 1 given 2 error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I have an issue where legacy code for pagination was implemented prior to me being hiring failed randomly today. I am running a heroku app with rails and using will_paginate for pagination. In my controller I have

`

```
def index
    @publications = Publication.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 11).order('sort_date DESC')
  end
```

`

in my view i have

`

```
<div class="container">
     <%= will_paginate @publications %>
</div>
```

`

It throws the following error(which is leading to a 500 error in turn): wrong number of arguments(given 2, expected 1) for will_paginate.

change the .paginate function parameters to be(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 11) as mentioned in the will_paginate documentation it still throws the same error. if i delete the per_page option it also still throws the same given 2 expected 1 error. i've also updated will-paginate and still get the same error

Comment: which version will_paginate you are using currently. I saw this issue in will_paginate gem https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/issues/638 which is resolved in recent versions.

Comment: @SampatBadhe i'm using 3.1.8... im an idiot, i just realized they're on version 3.3.x, i'll update the app and see if that works and update the question if it does! thanks for helping me have the aha moment :)

Comment: Protip: hashrockets and the "JSON style" colon syntax are just different notations for hash literals and it makes absolutely no difference which you are using as long as the keys are symbols.

Comment: The actual issue is the most likely [the separation of positional and keyword arguments in Ruby 3.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/). In Ruby 2.7 `::I18n.translate(defaults.shift, options.merge(:default => defaults, :scope => :will_paginate))` would coerce the hash into keywords and issue a warning. In Ruby 3 its treated as a normal positional argument and you need to explicitly use `**options`  to pass a hash as keyword arguments.  This change broke a lot of libraries.

Comment: You can downgrade Ruby to 2.7 to just get warnings instead so you can progressively update your dependencies while still letting your tests run.